# How to prevent Owin from redirect to Login on session expiration?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, adfs

We have a web application beaing authenticated with Owin and ADFS.
I have session timeout in 10 minutes, but I need to prevent redirection to Login when the session times out.

We have our own session management, but Owin is redirecting the user to the Login even before the 10 minutes are over.

In summary, does someone knows how to prevent Owin redirection process to login when session is over?

Thank you.

Comment: What do u want to do upon redirection

Comment: @NitinSingh I want to prevent redirection. I need to return a custom error code to be able to notify user about the session end and invoke signout manually.

Comment: Once session ends, you dont have any state so cannot logout

Comment: And is there some way to notify user before redirect to login? My main problem is that the site is getting redirected to the login without notify user about what is happening